# Passing data to another controller using MVP pattern iOS

Tags: ios, swift, mvp

I am using MVP design pattern. I have two ways of passing data to the another view controller which I'll mention below. I don't know which of them is correct and doesn't violate MVP pattern. I know this is very big question but it's really very important.

1) Using `init with presenter`, below am creating the view controller by passing the presenter which the view controller needs.

```
struct HotelTemplate {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var icon: String
}

class ListHotelPresenter: NSObject {

    private var data = [HotelTemplate]()

    func getPresenter(_ index: Int) -> HotelDetailsPresenter {
        let presenter = HotelDetailsPresenter(id: data[index].id, name: data[index].name, icon: data[index].icon)
        return presenter
    }
}

// InitialViewController
class ListHotelViewController: UIViewController {

    class func `init`(with presenter: ListHotelPresenter) -> ListHotelViewController {
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListHotelViewController") as! ListHotelViewController
        vc.presenter = presenter
        return vc
    }

    var presenter: ListHotelPresenter!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let detailPresenter = presenter.getPresenter(indexPath.row)
        let vc = HotelDetailsViewController.init(with: detailPresenter)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}

// ViewController that will be push
class HotelDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    class func `init`(with presenter: HotelDetailsPresenter) -> HotelDetailsViewController {
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HotelDetailsViewController") as! HotelDetailsViewController
        return vc
    }

    var presenter: HotelDetailsPresenter!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        presenter.loadHoteData()
    }
}

class HotelDetailsPresenter: NSObject {
    var hotelId: String
    var hotelName: String
    var hotelIcon: String

    init(id: String, name: String, icon: String) {
        self.hotelId = id
        self.hotelName = name
        self.hotelIcon = icon
    }

    func loadHoteData() {
        // Load hotel data.
        // Alamofire.request ..................
    }
}
```

2) By sending the `id, name, icon` and then initialising the presenter in the `viewDidLoad()`

```
struct HotelTemplate {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var icon: String
}

class ListHotelPresenter: NSObject {

    private var data = [HotelTemplate]()

    func getHotelName(_ index: Int) -> String {
        return data[index].name
    }

    func getHotelIcon(_ index: Int) -> String {
        return data[index].icon
    }

    func getHotelId(_ index: Int) -> String {
        return data[index].id
    }
}

class ListHotelViewController: UIViewController {

    var presenter: ListHotelPresenter!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HotelDetailsViewController") as! HotelDetailsViewController
        vc.id = presenter.getHotelId(indexPath.row)
        vc.name = presenter.getHotelName(indexPath.row)
        vc.icon = presenter.getHotelIcon(indexPath.row)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}

class HotelDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    var presenter: HotelDetailsPresenter!
    var id = ""
    var name = ""
    var icon = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        presenter = HotelDetailsPresenter(id: id, name: name, icon: icon)
        presenter.loadHoteData()
    }
}

class HotelDetailsPresenter: NSObject {
    var hotelId: String
    var hotelName: String
    var hotelIcon: String

    init(id: String, name: String, icon: String) {
        self.hotelId = id
        self.hotelName = name
        self.hotelIcon = icon
    }

    func loadHoteData() {
        // Load hotel data.
        // Alamofire.request ..................
    }
}
```

So below are my concerns:

1) Which one is correct? (I feel the first method is really very clean, but my senior told me that it violates the MVP pattern. I don't know how.)

2) Should the presenter property of the controller be public or private?

Answer (score 3):

In Objective-C, you can have a View that passes a Model around. We could forward-declare a model in the view controller's header file:

```
@class HotelTemplate;
```

In the .m file, I'd make sure not to `"#import HotelTemplate.h"`. This way, the model remained opaque. You can pass it around, but you can't look inside.

I don't know of any way to enforce this in Swift. So let me follow your example and pass the next presenter, instead of the next model. All we need is a way to set the View on the each presenter in `viewDidLoad()`. To prevent retain cycles, this will be a weak property.

First, here's the list view controller. I made it a UITableViewController.

```
final class ListHotelViewController: UITableViewController {
    private var presenter = ListHotelPresenter()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        presenter.setView(self)
        presenter.loadHotelData()
    }
}
```

The presenter will call it back through a protocol:

```
protocol ListHotelView: class {
    func redraw()
    func showDetails(nextPresenter: HotelDetailsPresenter)
}

extension ListHotelViewController: ListHotelView {
    func redraw() {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func showDetails(nextPresenter: HotelDetailsPresenter) {
        let vc = HotelDetailsViewController.init(with: nextPresenter)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Here's the table view's data source and delegate:

```
extension ListHotelViewController /* UITableViewDataSource */ {
    public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return presenter.hotelCount
    }

    public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Hotel", for: indexPath) as! HotelTableViewCell
        presenter.configure(cell: cell, row: indexPath.row)
        return cell
    }
}

extension ListHotelViewController /* UITableViewDelegate */ {
    public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        presenter.showDetails(row: indexPath.row)
    }
}
```

At each step, it defers to the Presenter. The Presenter has a weak link back to the View, but only through the protocol. It has no idea that the View is a ListHotelViewController. We should be able to implement the View with a bunch of `print(_)` statements instead, for a terminal-based interface.

```
final class ListHotelPresenter {
    private weak var view: ListHotelView?
    private var model: [HotelTemplate] = [] {
        didSet {
            view?.redraw()
        }
    }

    var hotelCount: Int {
        return model.count
    }

    func setView(_ view: ListHotelView) {
        self.view = view
    }

    func loadHotelData() {
        // Network request to load data into model. Let's pretend with dummy data:
        let hilton = HotelTemplate(id: "hilton", name: "Hilton", icon: "H")
        let radisson = HotelTemplate(id: "radisson", name: "Radisson", icon: "R")
        model = [hilton, radisson]
    }

    func configure(cell: HotelCell, row: Int) {
        let hotel = model[row]
        cell.show(name: hotel.name, icon: hotel.icon)
    }

    func showDetails(row: Int) {
        let nextPresenter = HotelDetailsPresenter(summaryModel: model[row])
        view?.showDetails(nextPresenter: nextPresenter)
    }
}
```

In `configure(cell:row:)`, the Presenter talks to the given cell. Note that the cell is also a protocol. With MVP, I really try to imagine how I'd use it to make a terminal-based interface. Here's the cell:

```
protocol HotelCell: class {
    func show(name: String, icon: String)
}

final class HotelTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {}

extension HotelTableViewCell: HotelCell {
    func show(name: String, icon: String) {
        textLabel?.text = name
        // Do something to show icon
    }
}
```

In practice, you'd add more to the table view cell. I just used a plain cell and its text label for this example.

Finally, we come to the pushed view controller.

```
final class HotelDetailsViewController: UIViewController {
    private var presenter: HotelDetailsPresenter!
    @IBOutlet private var textLabel: UILabel!

    static func `init`(with presenter: HotelDetailsPresenter) -> HotelDetailsViewController {
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HotelDetailsViewController")
                as! HotelDetailsViewController
        vc.presenter = presenter
        return vc
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        presenter.setView(self)
        presenter.show()
    }
}
```

I'm making the assumption that we'll immediately show the summary information we have, but that there's more to detail to come from a web service. That's done by this Presenter.

```
struct HotelDetails {
    let location: String
    // more details…
}

final class HotelDetailsPresenter {
    private weak var view: HotelDetailsView?
    private let summaryModel: HotelTemplate        
    private var detailsModel: HotelDetails? {
        didSet {
            guard let detailsModel = detailsModel else { return }
            view?.showDetails(location: detailsModel.location)
        }
    }

    init(summaryModel: HotelTemplate) {
        self.summaryModel = summaryModel
    }

    func setView(_ view: HotelDetailsView) {
        self.view = view
    }

    func show() {
        view?.show(name: summaryModel.name, icon: summaryModel.icon)
        // Network request to load data into detailsModel
    }
}
```

As usual, the Presenter tells the View what to do through a protocol:

```
protocol HotelDetailsView: class {
    func show(name: String, icon: String)
    func showDetails(location: String)
}

extension HotelDetailsViewController: HotelDetailsView {
    func show(name: String, icon: String) {
        textLabel?.text = name
        // Do something to show icon
    }

    func showDetails(location: String) {
        // Show other hotel details we loaded
    }
}
```

As you can see, the properties are private. To support unit testing, we might need to relax that using `private(set)` so that only the setters are private.

Answer (score 0):

Hey as per apple guidance [Model-View-Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) both are okay but the second one is more readable and easy to understand to first one with some changes please check the code.

```
class ListHotelViewController: UIViewController{
private var presenter: ListHotelPresenter!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HotelDetailsViewController") as! HotelDetailsViewController
    vc.objHotelTemplate = presenter.getHotelTemplate(indexPath.row)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
}
class HotelDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

private var presenter: HotelDetailsPresenter!
var objHotelTemplate:HotelTemplate!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    presenter = HotelDetailsPresenter(id: objHotelTemplate.id, name: objHotelTemplate.name, icon: objHotelTemplate.icon)
    presenter.loadHoteData()
}
```

}

Comment: I am no longer using `Model View Controller`. I am using `Model View Presenter`. So my Views aren't suppose to know the Model.